# Your PostgreSQL is too old- error on centos 6.5 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, centos

i am trying to run `bundle install` .

but i am getting error here is my error log from console-

```
Your PostgreSQL is too old. Either install an older version of this gem or upgrade your database to
at least PostgreSQL-9.2.
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'pg'
```

postgres --version

```
postgres (PostgreSQL) 8.4.20
```

how can i resolve this error without updating postgres db on centos server?

Comment: You want to update PostgreSQL to v12. Anything else is playing with the life of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agreed with comments you should update your postgres, as it has been almost 10 year and you are using very old version of database so it is very risky.

You can downgrade your PG gem version by editing your Gem file and putt following line in it instead of following

```
gem 'pg'
```

to

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.11'
```

Now run command

```
bundle
```

And try to run it should work. as I tried on Rails 6 and it work smoothly, but there would be many changes happen in the gem as now it is version 2+ and you are using before 1 version.